# Scraping; how do I ignore "?" (and other forbidden characters) and preserve as much of the filename as possible?

Tags: javascript, screen-scraping

**Code**: https://github.com/anniegiang/izone-private-mail-archive

**Context**: Scraping "mail" from an app (more accurately, its server). One mail has "?" in subject line. Filenames are saved as the subject line, which I want to preserve.

**Problem**: I get this error

```
 [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\IZONE\izone-private-mail-archive\out\이채연\images\m4356__Tue-Mar-03-2020__집중유형분석?__.jpeg'] {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'D:\\IZONE\\izone-private-mail-archive\\out\\이채연\\images\\m4356__Tue-Mar-03-2020__집중유형분석?__.jpeg'
}
```

**My current fix**: changed subject to false in userSettings.js

```
  module.exports = {
  userId: '',
  accessToken: '',
  mailFolderName: 'out', // by default
  mailFileName: {
    date: true,
    subject: false,
  },
};
```

**Question**: Is there a way to write the filenames and specifically ignore forbidden characters? Is this even the right question for solving this?

Answer (score 0):

On [line 68 of utils.js](https://github.com/anniegiang/izone-private-mail-archive/blob/master/utils.js#L68), the `fileName` function only replaces spaces and forward slashes:

```
return fileName.replace(/ /g, '-').replace(/\//g, '-');
```

Instead, you could replace all unwanted characters at once:

```
//                          ?  /  |  \  <  >  : *
return fileName.replace(/( |\?|\/|\||\\|\<|\>|:|\*)+/g, '-');
```

[Regex101 explanation](https://regex101.com/r/7Puqol/1)

Here is a demo:

```js
function demo(str) {
  console.log(str.replace(/( |\?|\/|\||\\|\<|\>|:|\*)+/g, '-'));
}

demo(`Hello world?`); // Hello-world-
demo(`<Hello::world>`); // -Hello-world-
```